# Unable to bulk index to elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have json file as shown here,

```
{ "index": { "_index": "volvo", "_type": "user" }}
{"dn": " cn=s,o=VCC\n", "changetype": " add\n", "mail": " com\n", "surname": " s\n", "givenname": " s\n", "cn": " su2\n", "objectclass": [" inetOrgPerson\n", " srvprvUserAux\n", " organizationalPerson\n", " Person\n", " ndsLoginProperties\n", " Top\n", " srvprvEntityAux\n"]}
{ "index": { "_index": "volvo", "_type": "user" }}
{"dn": " cn=s1,o=VCC\n", "changetype": " add\n", "mail": " com\n", "surname": " sa\n", "givenname": " su\n", "cn": " s\n", "objectclass": [" inetOrgPerson\n", " srvprvUserAux\n", " organizationalPerson\n", " Person\n", " ndsLoginProperties\n", " Top\n", " srvprvEntityAux\n"]}
```

when i try to bulk index this to my elasticsearch,
i get the following error,

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('�' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@4914595e; line: 2, column: 2]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('�' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@4914595e; line: 2, column: 2]"},"status":500}
```

Can you figure out whats the issue with my json.

Comment: Most likely an error with the Byte Order Mark (BOM) - or the encoding in general - in your file.

Comment: how do you remove it from that json file.

Comment: Notepad++ has a tool to change the file encoding.

Comment: you json has some Unexpected chars due to which you are getting exceptions , i can see `\n` remove this and try

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error while bulk indexing and resolved the issue by changing the file encoding. Using Notepad++ I changed the file encoding from UTF-8-BOM to UTF-8 and was able to complete bulk index operation.